# How do I make a Silverlight Progressbar update according to its value?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am making a Progressbar as part of my Silverlight application that is triggered when a user clicks a button. For now, I just have it update by random increments at random times so that I can make sure it works as I need it to. The code that updates the value of the Progressbar is rather trivial, but the actual display of the Progressbar never updates. The code I use for this is here:

```
Random randomGen = new Random();

while (submitProgress.Value < submitProgress.Maximum)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(randomGen.Next(100, 500));
    submitProgress.Value += randomGen.Next(3, 7);
}
```

The XAML I use to create the Progressbar is here:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Width="400" IsIndeterminate="False" 
Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="0" Name="submitProgress"></ProgressBar>
```

To be clear, the Progressbar does update to its completed state when it is finished, but there are no intermediate updates from start to finish. If you need any more information from me, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What thread are you running the process on?  If you are running on the main thread, the UI will not update until processing is finished.  I recommend using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to do the processing.  You will need to use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) then when updating the UI or updating an object bound to the UI.

Comment: The process is running on the main thread. I don't have much experience with threads, which is why I didn't know the UI would freeze if I used Thread.Sleep(). I've used it in a few applications before without an issue, but now that I think about it, I was trying to freeze the UI in those applications. I'll take a look at those links and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: I just did some research on BackgroundWorkers and Dispatchers, and the Progressbar now works exactly as I need it to. Thank you very much, cadrell.