# VLCJ: Updating the progress bar as the video progresses

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, vlcj

Please have a look at the following code

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.bean.playerbean.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventAdapter;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerEventListener;

public class PlayMedia extends JFrame
{
    private EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent m;
    private JProgressBar bar;

    public PlayMedia()
    {

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(
      RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "c:\\program files\\videolan\\vlc"
    );
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);


        m = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        m.getMediaPlayer().addMediaPlayerEventListener(new UpdateBar());

        bar = new JProgressBar(0,100);
        bar.setStringPainted(true);

        getContentPane().add(m);
        getContentPane().add(bar,"South");


        this.setSize(500,500);
        this.validate();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


         m.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("C:\\Users\\Yohan\\Desktop\\video.avi");   

    }

    private class UpdateBar extends MediaPlayerEventAdapter
    {
        public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer mp, float pos)
        {
            int value = Math.min(100, Math.round(pos * 100.0f));
            bar.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
            @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    new PlayMedia();
                }
            });


    }
}
```

In here, video is playing fine, but the progress bar is not getting updated. How to update the progress bar as the video plays? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ProgressBars in Swing, but I have used them in Silverlight, so I would think most of the principles would be the same. Check out the answer to my question here: 
[How do I make a Silverlight Progressbar update according to its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245735/how-do-i-make-a-silverlight-progressbar-update-according-to-its-value) It may not show you exactly how to do this in Swing, but it doesn't seem like you're using threading in your code, which is what my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

for some unknown reason positionChanged() isn't called during the video.
try to use timeChanged() istead, it worked for me!

```
public void positionChanged (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer , long time) { ... }
```